# Cocos2dx 2.2.3 Undefined symbols for architecture arm64 :: WebPInitDecoderConfigInternal

Tags: c++, ios, cocos2d-x

I am developing cocos2dx game. when i run game on simuloator that works good but when start to archive follwing error are produce IN XCODE 6.0

Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:

"_WebPInitDecoderConfigInternal", referenced from:
      cocos2d::CCImage::_initWithWebpData(void*, int) in libcocos2dx.a(CCImageCommonWebp.o)

"_WebPGetFeaturesInternal", referenced from:
      cocos2d::CCImage::_initWithWebpData(void*, int) in libcocos2dx.a(CCImageCommonWebp.o)

"_WebPDecode", referenced from:
      cocos2d::CCImage::_initWithWebpData(void*, int) in libcocos2dx.a(CCImageCommonWebp.o)

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Check the your project architecture and build architecture settings

Comment: sounds like at least one target doesn't include arm64 / armv7s architecture

Comment: all 4 target include arm64/arm7s..and yes i work on xcode 6 and cocos2dx-2.2.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have shouldd be cocos2dx V.3.3 to Support arm64..because older cocos2dx version not support arm 64 bit . its only support 32 bit and apple must be approved 64 bit app from 1st february 2015. Thanx

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade to cocos2d-x v2.2.6. This version supports 64bit.

http://www.cocos2d-x.org/news/386